# Flash Builder, export release build error

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am unable to do an export build for an Apple ios from flex. 
I get the following error when i try to export.

[image]

how do i get around this error.
Also i able to successfully export for android.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably due to some characteristics of your flex project: too many classes or linked projects or assets or whatever.

Some months ago we posted some recurrent [problems regarding the development with Adobe AIR for iOS](http://translate.google.es/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=es&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://nosmoke.cycle-it.com/2012/08/07/desarrollo-de-aplicaciones-con-adobe-air-para-ios-problemas-y-soluciones/&act=url). The blog post is in spanish so I'm linking to a translated page by Google (I hope it is readable).

Anyways, what we listed there is the following:

1. Increase your java heap size memory (it didn't work for us). When you compile a flex project it uses the mxmlc compiler which is implemented in java (at least some parts of it are implemented in java). Giving more memory could make the exportation work for you (I don't think so though).
2. Switch your Adobe AIR SDK version to latest [version 3.4](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html)
3. Try to export your application using a Mac OS instead of a Windows machine (if you have one available for you).

Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: I dont think it was a memory issue, i had given it enough memory, also i was using the latest version then.(we chucked flex for HTML5)...guess all that was left was to try it on a MAC. Still couldnt rely on flex, cos of future support issues, so HTML5 it was.

Comment: In my experience, switching to the latest AIR SDK (3.4) on a windows machine was enough to solve our issue. AIR 3.3 has the issues you're describing here. However AIR 3.3 works quite well on a MAC OS machine.
Anyways, Flex is not "supported" by Adobe (it is now an Apache project), but the Flash Platform (which includes AIR) is actively developed and mantained nowadays by Adobe. We got some mobile projects working fine using Adobe AIR. Sorry to hear it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I was using the latest SDK. It was 3.4 and i still had that issue.(On windows) And we had only a couple of days to decide between HTML or FLEX. And Adobe had  announced that it was incubating Flex but no release date was given which had put us in a fix. I had a strong feeling about Flex, would have actually finalized on it would our problem also some other issues had resolved. It was much easier to code in flex than html. Still we decided to go to HTML, cos we had an option to switch, since our app was pretty small sized